# Why library() or require() should not be used in a R package

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, dependencies

My goal is to create R package which use other library such as grid and ggplot2.
According to
https://tinyheero.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/07/26/making-your-first-R-package.html, it is said that library() or require() should not be used in a R package.

My questions are:
1)Is there a reason? (because, although I put library("ggplot2") and library("grid") in my R script in my package, it still worked).
2)Do I have to delete library("ggplot2") and library("grid") in my code and put "::" such as ggplot2::geom.segment()?

Is there an efficient way to convert script to the one for package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never use `library()` or `require()` in a package, because they affect the user's search list, possibly causing errors for the user.

For example, both the `dplyr` and `stats` packages export a function called `filter`.  If a user had only `library(stats)`, then `filter` would mean `stats::filter`, but if your package called `library(dplyr)`, the user might suddenly find that `filter` means `dplyr::filter`, and things would break.

There are a couple of alternatives for your package.  You can import functions from another package by listing it in the `Imports:` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file and specifying the imports in the `NAMESPACE` file.  (The `roxygen2` package can make these changes for you automatically if you put appropriate comments in your `.R` source files, e.g.

```
#' @importFrom jsonlite toJSON unbox
```

before a function that uses those to import `toJSON()` and `unbox()` from the `jsonlite` package.)

The other way to do it is using the `::` notation.  Then you can still list a package in the `Imports:` field of `DESCRIPTION`, but use code like

```
jsonlite::toJSON(...)
```

every time you want to call it.  Alternatively, if you don't want a strong dependence on `jsonlite`, you can put `jsonlite` in `Suggests:`, and wrap any uses of it in code like

```
if (requireNamespace("jsonlite")) {
  jsonlite::toJSON(...)
}
```

Then people who don't have that package will still be able to run your function, but it may skip some operations that require `jsonlite`.